# Is there a phrase or word that describes misinformation expressed in an articulate way?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

I'm looking for something similar to "pseudo-profound" or "eloquent poppy cock". I'm thinking of highly inaccurate academic papers and 'scientific' articles. Saying something asinine in a smart way?

Comment: _Fake news! Sad!_

Comment: Shakespeare thought "The devil can cite scripture for his purpose. An evil soul producing holy witness..." --  The Merchant of Venice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sophistry](http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict?Form=Dict2&Database=gcide&Query=sophistry), 2:

> The practice of a sophist; fallacious reasoning; reasoning
>       sound in appearance only.

[Demagoguery](http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict?Form=Dict2&Database=gcide&Query=demagoguery), 1:

> impassioned appeals to the prejudices and emotions of the
>       populace.

**EDIT:** In your case *sophistry* should seem the better choice because the [sophists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophist) of old studied the laws of logic and reasoning by breaking them in ways imperceptible to the unsuspecting. See also a [list of logical fallacies](http://utminers.utep.edu/omwilliamson/engl1311/fallacies.htm).

Comment: This answer could be improved with a short explanation of why the OP might choose one or the other of these, and how they apply to the context provided.

Comment: Easier said than done, Kit.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use: equivocation or circumlocution.

[Equivocation](https://www.google.com/search?q=equivocation&oq=equi&gs_l=serp.3.0.35i39k1j0i67k1l5j0i20k1j0i67k1l2j0.103121.103698.0.104655.4.4.0.0.0.0.153.497.2j2.4.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.4.497.dJ1QPfRcIhI):

> the use of ambiguous language to conceal the truth or to avoid committing oneself; prevarication.

[Circumlocution](https://www.google.com/search?q=circumlocution&oq=circumlocution&gs_l=serp.3..35i39k1j0j0i20k1j0l7.19006.22738.0.22908.14.14.0.0.0.0.129.1439.5j9.14.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.14.1437...0i67k1j0i131k1.ZP8mwHdOHvY):

> the use of many words where fewer would do, especially in a deliberate attempt to be vague or evasive.

Comment: The [help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) says: '*Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*'

Comment: Oy! Sigh. Okay. I'll make updates tomorrow. Does this not seem a bit ridiculous at times? It's too short, it's too long, not succinct enough, overly verbose, now not enough citations, now too many... Sorry its not a personal jab. No really. Its not. Just seeing a lot of comments about those kinds of things :/

Comment: yeah, every site is different. We like long answers here :) once you get the hang of it, it's fine!

Comment: Guideline:  Post enough so the reader is not forced to click on your link to get the essence of what you want to say.  Post the link so that a reader who wants to learn more can do so easily.  Not necessary to post so much that the reader learns all there is to know about a subject by reading your post -- although sometimes a post does just this, very successfully.

Comment: Ping me when you have edited, and I will upvote.

Comment: Thanks guys. Got it. I'll do so. I'm on my phone at the moment so it's a bit difficult but I will definitely update it when I get back to my computer; as well as keep the rest in mind. Thanks again.

Comment: Updated with quoted material.